# Explicit use of LambdaMetafactory

Tags: java, metaprogramming, java-8, lambda

I'm trying to explicitly use LambdaMetafactory.metafactory, I can't understand why it works only with the Runnable functional interface. For Example, this code does what it is expected (it prints "hello world"):

```
public class MetafactoryTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class);
        MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(Runnable.class);
        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller, 
                                                      "run", 
                                                      invokedType, 
                                                      methodType, 
                                                      caller.findStatic(MetafactoryTest.class, "print", methodType), 
                                                      methodType);
        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
        Runnable r = (Runnable) factory.invoke();
        r.run();
    }
    
    private static void print() {
        System.out.println("hello world"); 
    }    
}
```

The problem arises when I try to use a different functional interface, such as Supplier. The following code does not work:

```
public class MetafactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(String.class);
        MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(Supplier.class);
        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller, 
                                                      "get", 
                                                      invokedType, 
                                                      methodType, 
                                                      caller.findStatic(MetafactoryTest.class, "print", methodType), 
                                                      methodType);
        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
        Supplier<String> r = (Supplier<String>) factory.invoke();
        System.out.println(r.get());        
    }
    private static String print() {
        return "hello world";
    }    
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: metafactorytest.MetafactoryTest$$Lambda$1/258952499.get()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at metafactorytest.MetafactoryTest.main(MetafactoryTest.java:29)
```

Shouldn't the two snippets of code work in a similar way, what is the problem in the second one?

Moreover, the following code which should be equivalent, works well:

```
public class MetafactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Supplier<String> r = (Supplier<String>) () -> print();
        System.out.println(r.get());        
    }

    private static String print() {
        return "hello world";
    }    
}
```

**Edit**

Another solution that avoids changing the method return type is to define a new functional interface:

```
public class MetafactoryTest {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Test {
        String getString();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(String.class);
        MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(Test.class);
        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller, 
                                                      "getString", 
                                                      invokedType, 
                                                      methodType, 
                                                      caller.findStatic(MetafactoryTest.class, "print", methodType), 
                                                      methodType);
        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
        Test r = (Test) factory.invoke();
        System.out.println(r.getString());        
    }
    
    private static String print() {
        return "hello world";
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the method name "run" you pass as the second argument. Runnable has a "run" method. Supplier does not.

Comment: That was an error (The Runnable case works only with "run"), but also with get the second snippet gives that error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference between Runnable and Supplier is that Supplier uses a generic type.

At runtime Supplier doesn't have a String get() method, it has Object get(). But the method you implement returns a String. You need to distinguish between those 2 types. Like this:

```
public class MetafactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(Object.class);
        MethodType actualMethodType = MethodType.methodType(String.class);
        MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(Supplier.class);
        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller, 
                                                      "get", 
                                                      invokedType, 
                                                      methodType, 
                                                      caller.findStatic(MetafactoryTest.class, "print", actualMethodType), 
                                                      methodType);
        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
        Supplier<String> r = (Supplier<String>) factory.invoke();
        System.out.println(r.get());
    }

    private static String print() {
        return "hello world";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Would this work if the print method contained an argument?

Comment: If the print method needs an argument it cannot be used to implement the "Runnable" or the "Supplier" interface.

Comment: Is their anything that can be used? Which would you recommend? In my instance, I'm trying to invoke a non-static function that returns a boolean and takes in one or more Strings as parameters.

Comment: @Sahil Gupta: you can bind values as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27605965/2711488). The first bound value will be the method receiver, if the target method is not `static`, other bound values map to the method’s parameters left to right. The function parameters, if any, map to the remaining unbound method parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the game but LambdaMetaFactory almost drove me crazy. Very hard to see which parameter goes where. Made an example that shows the different types a bit more explicit by naming them according to their role.

```
    class Instance {
        public RetSub get(Par p) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            return null;
        }
    }
    static class Ret {}
    static class RetSub extends Ret {}
    static class Par {}
    static class ParSub extends Par {}
    interface If {
        Ret method(ParSub p);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstance() throws Throwable {
        Instance instance = new Instance();
        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller,
            "method",
            MethodType.methodType(If.class, Instance.class), //
            MethodType.methodType(Ret.class, ParSub.class), //
            caller.findVirtual(Instance.class, "get", MethodType.methodType(RetSub.class, Par.class)), //
            MethodType.methodType(RetSub.class, ParSub.class));

        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();

        If iff = (If) factory.invoke(instance);
        iff.method(new ParSub());
    }
```

I think it was hard because I missed the semantics of the parameters.

- `invokedName` – Obviously the method name in the interface
- `invokedType` – This is the hard one. This is the MethodType of the MethodHandle returned by the `CallSite.getTarget()`. The first argument is the type of the interface we're trying to make (`If`), the second argument is only needed when we access an instance method and is the instance type (`Instance`).
- `samMethodType` – This is the *exact* method type of the function we try to implement. In this case 'Ret method(ParSub p)`.
- `implMethod` – A method handle. It must be possible to convert the parameters and return type of the interface method we create to this method handle.
- `instantiationMethodType` – A runtime check to verify some parameters and return types fall within narrower or the same types than the interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is another example with a more easy to understand variable names:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Consumer<String> consumer = s -> System.out.println("CONSUMED: " + s + ".");

        consumer.accept("foo");

        MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();

        MethodType lambdaBodyMethodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class);
        MethodHandle lambdaBody = caller.findStatic(
                Demo.class, "my$lambda$main$0", lambdaBodyMethodType);

        // Because of the type erasure we must use Object here
        // instead of String (Consumer<String> -> Consumer).
        MethodType functionalInterfaceMethodType =
                MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class);

        // we must return consumer, no closure -> no additional parameters
        MethodType callSiteType = MethodType.methodType(Consumer.class);

        CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                // provided by invokedynamic:
                caller, "accept", callSiteType,
                // additional bootstrap method arguments:
                functionalInterfaceMethodType,
                lambdaBody,
                lambdaBodyMethodType);

        MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
        Consumer<String> r = (Consumer<String>) factory.invoke();

        r.accept("foo");
        r.accept("bar");
    }

    private static void my$lambda$main$0(String s) {
        System.out.println("CONSUMED: " + s + ".");
    }
}
```

Because `LambdaMetafactory` creates a synthetic factory class that then 
is used to create target interface, `callSiteType` has a type of this factory `create()` method. This `create()` method is called implicitly by `invokedynamic` - `LambdaMetafactory` returns a `CallSite` that has a method reference to the create method. For lambdas with closures you will call the factory like `factory.create(capturedValue1, ..., capturedValueN)` and so you must modify `callSiteType` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a situation where I needed to call a function passing some parameter to it. Similar to @Sahil Gupta question. I managed to solve it using a BiFunction with some adjustments:

```
public void testFunctionWithParameter() throws Throwable {
    SimpleBean simpleBean = new SimpleBean();

    MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(BiFunction.class);
    MethodType biFunc = MethodType.methodType(String.class, String.class);
    MethodHandle target = caller.findVirtual(SimpleBean.class, "simpleFunction", biFunc);
    MethodType func = target.type();


    CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            caller,
            "apply",
            invokedType,
            func.generic(),
            target,
            MethodType.methodType(String.class, SimpleBean.class, String.class)
    );

    BiFunction<SimpleBean, String, String> fullFunction = (BiFunction<SimpleBean, String, String>) site.getTarget().invokeExact();


    System.out.println(fullFunction.apply(simpleBean, "FOO"));

}

private class SimpleBean {
    public String simpleFunction(String in) {
        return "The parameter was " + in;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone.