# How to get Method Reference for all methods in a class (Java)?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

**Method Reference** for a specific method in Java 8 can be obtained as `Class::Method`. But how to get the method reference of all methods of a class?

All the desired methods have *different* method names, but the **same** type signature. Also, the names of the methods is **not known** before hand.

Example:

```
class Test {
    public static double op0(double a) { ... }
    public static double op1(double a) { ... }
    public static double op2(double a) { ... }
    public static double op3(double a) { ... }
    public static double op4(double a) { ... }
}
```

The method reference to a known method `op0` can be obtained as:

```
DoubleFunction<Double> f = Test::op0;
```

But, how to get the method references of all methods in the class?

Comment: You mean how to get these in the IDE's content assist?

Comment: No, to get the method references, so that they can be called at a later point of time. This is possible using `Reflection`, but i was looking for an easier alternative.

Comment: Also the statement *the desired methods have different function names, but the same function signature* is wrong. The signature includes the method name and the list of parameters. The return-type is not part of the method signature.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be called [Type Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no solution that works without Reflection as the dynamic discovery of existing methods *is* a reflective operation. However, once methods are discovered and a method reference instance (or the dynamic equivalent of it) has been created, the actual invocation of the code runs without Reflection:

```
class Test {
    public static double op0(double a) { ... }
    public static double op1(double a) { ... }
    public static double op2(double a) { ... }
    public static double op3(double a) { ... }
    public static double op4(double a) { ... }

    static final Map<String, DoubleUnaryOperator> OPS;
    static {
        HashMap<String, DoubleUnaryOperator> map=new HashMap<>();
        MethodType type=MethodType.methodType(double.class, double.class);
        MethodType inT=MethodType.methodType(DoubleUnaryOperator.class);
        MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
        for(Method m:Test.class.getDeclaredMethods()) try {
          if(!Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())) continue;
          MethodHandle mh=l.unreflect(m);
          if(!mh.type().equals(type)) continue;
          map.put(m.getName(), (DoubleUnaryOperator)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            l, "applyAsDouble", inT, type, mh, type).getTarget().invokeExact());
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        OPS=Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

Once the class has been initialized, you can invoke a particular op without Reflection using `OPS.get(name).applyAsDouble(doubleValue)` or invoke all ops using, e.g.

```
OPS.forEach((name,op)-> System.out.println(name+'('+42+") => "+op.applyAsDouble(42)));
```

Comment: Thanks @Holger. I had already found your answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557829/faster-alternatives-to-javas-reflection) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602758/java-access-bean-methods-with-lambdametafactory/27605965) which solved my problem. That helps me to do the same with instance methods. It is indeed really fast.

Comment: why did you use `DoubleUnaryOperator` instead of `DoubleFunction`? and how is `"applyAsDouble"` method name is enough without specifying the class or interface name?

Comment: `DoubleFunction` is a function which consumes a `double` and returns an `Object`; `DoubleUnaryOperator` consumes a `double` and returns a `double`, thus perfectly matches the signature of the methods in your example. The desired `interface` is derived from the return type of the `invokedynamic` instruction; in our Reflective usage it appears twice. The `invokedType` parameter (the `inT` variable) specifies the return type and our `invokeExact()` call is *signature polymorphic* and uses our type cast `(DoubleUnaryOperator)` to determine the return type which, of course, must match with `inT`.

Comment: Hi, and what if the methods "op" would not be static, so reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type. How to obtain this kind of map then?

Comment: @Kristoff you have to decide. Do you want to bind (capture) a specific instance at creation time, so it will always be used when you evaluate the `DoubleUnaryOperator`, or do you want to pass an instance (potentially being different every time) each time you evaluate the function. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27605965/2711488) discusses both options on a single example. However, for the second case you would need a custom interface for consuming an object and a `double` and producing a `double` (unless you are ok with boxing).