# Given a `Class` object, get a method reference to `toString`

Tags: java, lambda, enums, java-8, method-reference

If you have only a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object, how does one get a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to a method such as `toString`? Later we will have instances of this particular class on which we will invoke this method via the method reference.

For example, consider a Java enum, a subclass of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html). Here `T` is defined as `<T extends Enum>`.

```
Class c = MyEnum.class
…
Function< T , String> f = c :: toString ;
```

I get an error saying "invalid method reference".

Answer (score 7):

For `toString`, it's as easy as `Object::toString`.  All `Object`s have `toString`, so you can use it right there.  For other methods where you don't know statically that the object has that method, there's no easy way; you have to write a lambda that does it the ugly reflective way.

Answer (score 4):

If you can access your `Class` object using a class literal in the form `Class<MyEnum> c=MyEnum.class;`, it implies that the type `MyEnum` is known at compile time. In this case, the `Class` object is an unnecessary detour. You can access all methods of the class `MyEnum` using the form `MyEnum::methodName`, e.g.

```
Function<MyEnum,String> f=MyEnum::toString;
```

This is what the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type) describes as “Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type”. It doesn’t require an actual `MyEnum` instance.

Nevertheless, there is no point in dealing with `MyEnum` when you want to have a `Function<T,…>` as that function must be able to consume arbitrary instances of `T`, not necessarily being `MyEnum`. So this function can only use methods existing in `T` and it doesn’t need to search them in `MyEnum`.

Since your target method is not specific to `MyEnum`, that’s possible:

```
Function<T,String> f=T::toString;
```

But [as already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32241154/2711488), the method `toString` is defined in `java.lang.Object`, so you may also use the form

```
Function<T,String> f=Object::toString;
```

as a method declared for all objects may also get invoked on instances of `T`. Though even this is a bit pointless as you can also use

```
Function<Object,String> f=Object::toString;
```

reflecting the ability to consume any instance of `Object`, not just `T`. Carefully written Generic code will always use wildcards to avoid unnecessary restrictions regarding its input. So it will accept a function which can *consume* `T` (which implies the ability to consume `MyEnum`) without requiring its type parameter to exactly match that type. For example:

[`<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)
`map`, applied on a `Stream<T>` will accept a `Function<Object,…>` as `Object` is a supertype of `T`…

---

So you can use `T::methodName` to access every method available for the bounds of that type, i.e. in your case you can use all methods of `Enum` and, of course, `Object`, but no methods specific to `MyEnum` not present in its supertypes. This isn’t different to ordinary method invocations you try to apply on instances of `T`. Further, a method not present in `T` wouldn’t be eligible for creating a valid `Function<T,…>` anyway.

---

If you want to create `Function` instances for methods not known at compile-time, you will have to use Reflection, and this is the only case where you have to deal with `Class` objects (in the context of method references). The second example of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27605965/2711488) shows how to create a `Function` for an instance method returning an object but that’s really only for those who know precisely what they are doing…

Note also that such reflectively created `Function`s have to use raw types as their appropriate generic type can’t be declared as it would refer to a type not present at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying here, is to get the reference of `toString()` for the class `Class`, which is probably not what you intended. As `toString()` is defined for all objects, this should work (not tested):

```
Function< T , String> f = t -> t.toString();
```