# Is dynamic method invocation using LambdaMetafactory thread safe?

Tags: java, reflection, thread-safety, lambda-metafactory

I'm using Java reflection to invoke methods dynamically in runtime. But I'm advised not to use it since its not thread safe. So I searched for alternatives for reflection and found this LambdaMetaFactory [Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775676/explicit-use-of-lambdametafactory). I want to know if it's thread safe or not to proceed further.

Comment: In case you’re talking about the standard Reflection API of Java, it *is* thread safe. The advice you got, is more than questionable. But to answer your literal question, of course, the `LambdaMetaFactory` is thread safe. It’s the runtime backend for the language feature of lambda expressions and method references. How would the language work if it couldn’t rely on it?

Comment: Thanks @Holger. Yes, It's standard reflection API of Java.